# spring 3 autowire

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using spring3 and hibernate 3 to build my application, I can't autowire the session factory

```
  package com.dao;
  import java.util.List;
  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

  import com.gepmag.model.Message;


  @Repository("iMessageTicketDao")
  public class MessageTicketDaoImpl implements IMessageTicketDao {

 @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void saveMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(message);
}




@Override
public List<Message> listTicketMessages(Long IdTicket) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Message> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Message where IdTicket=?")
            .setParameter(0, IdTicket).list();

    return list;
}

@Override
public void deleteMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(message);
}

@Override
public void updateMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(message);
}

@Override
public Message getMessageById(int idMessage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Message> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Message where where IdMessage=?")
            .setParameter(0, idMessage).list();
    return (Message) list.get(0);
}

@Override
public List<Message> listAllMessages() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Message> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Message").list();
    return list;
}

 }
```

And context xml configuration:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  

xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd ">



   <context:annotation-config/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gepmag" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />
 <!-- <context:annotation-driven/> -->  
  <mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"

    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="viewClass"

        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />

    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"

    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />

    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />

    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />

    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"

                                           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gepmag.model"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">

        <list>

            <value>com.model.Client</value>
            <value>com.model.Erreurs</value>
            <value>com.model.Message</value>
        </list>

    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">

        <props>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>

        </props>

    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"

    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">

    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />

</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"

    class="com.service.MessageBundle">  

    <property name="basename" value="com.service.MessageBundle" />  
</bean>

  </beans>
```

I always have this exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in    context with path [/PortailSupport] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.gepmag.dao.MessageTicketDaoImpl.saveMessage(MessageTicketDaoImpl.java:49)
        at   com.gepmag.service.TicketMessageServiceImpl.saveMessage(TicketMessageServiceImpl.java:48)
```

this is the service

```
 package com.gepmag.service;





 @Service("iTicketMessageService")
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
 public class TicketMessageServiceImpl implements ITicketMessageService {



  @Autowired(required=true)
  private IMessageTicketDao iMessageTicketDao;



@Override
public void saveMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iMessageTicketDao.saveMessage(message);
}

@Override
public List<Message> listTicketMessages(Long IdTicket) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Message> list = iMessageTicketDao.listTicketMessages(IdTicket);
    return list;
}


@Override
public void deleteMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iMessageTicketDao.deleteMessage(message);
}


@Override
public void updateMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iMessageTicketDao.updateMessage(message);
}

@Override
public Message getMessageById(int idMessage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Message message = iMessageTicketDao.getMessageById(idMessage);
    return message;
}

@Override
public List<Message> listAllMessages() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Message> list = iMessageTicketDao.listAllMessages();
    return list;
}
```

}

my controller

```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/forms/ticket")
  public class TicketController {


@Autowired
private TicketMessageServiceImpl iTicketMessageService ;


@RequestMapping(value="/addticket", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String addTicket(Map model) {

    TicketForm ticket =  new TicketForm();
    List<CategorieTicket> categorieList = LoadCategorieList();
    List<SeveriteTicket> severiteList = LoadSeveriteList();
    List<PrioriteTicket> prioriteList = LoadPrioriteList();
    List<ProblemeTicket> problemeList = LoadProblemeList(); 
    List<EtatSysteme> etatSystemeList = LoadEtatSysteme();
    List<ContexteProblemeTicket> contexteList = LoadContexteProblemeTicket();
    List<EtatInstance> etatInstanceList = LoadEtatInstance();

    model.put("ticket", ticket);
    model.put("categorieList", categorieList);
    model.put("severiteList", severiteList);
    model.put("prioriteList", prioriteList);
    model.put("problemeList", problemeList);
    model.put("etatSystemeList", etatSystemeList);
    model.put("contexteList", contexteList);
    model.put("etatInstanceList", etatInstanceList);

    return "newticket";
}

public List<CategorieTicket> LoadCategorieList(){

    List <CategorieTicket>categorieList = new ArrayList<CategorieTicket>();
    categorieList.add(new CategorieTicket(1,"Nouveau Besoin","description du nouveau besoin"));
    categorieList.add(new CategorieTicket(2,"Anomalie","description de l'anomalie"));
    categorieList.add(new CategorieTicket(3,"incident de production","description de l'incident de la production"));
    categorieList.add(new CategorieTicket(4,"crise de production","description du crise de la production"));

    return categorieList;
}

public List<SeveriteTicket> LoadSeveriteList(){

    List<SeveriteTicket> severiteList = new ArrayList<SeveriteTicket>();
    severiteList.add(new SeveriteTicket(1,"Bloquant","description de la sévérité bloquante"));
    severiteList.add(new SeveriteTicket(2,"Critique","description de la sévérité critique"));
    severiteList.add(new SeveriteTicket(3,"Majeur","description de la sévérité majeure"));
    severiteList.add(new SeveriteTicket(4,"Mineur","description de la sévérité mineur"));

    return severiteList;
}

public List<PrioriteTicket> LoadPrioriteList(){

    List<PrioriteTicket> PrioriteList = new ArrayList<PrioriteTicket>();
    PrioriteList.add(new PrioriteTicket(1,"Faible","priorité faible"));
    PrioriteList.add(new PrioriteTicket(2,"Moyenne","priorité moyenne"));
    PrioriteList.add(new PrioriteTicket(3,"Haute","priorité forte"));

    return PrioriteList;
}

public List<ProblemeTicket> LoadProblemeList(){

    List<ProblemeTicket> ProblemeList  = new ArrayList<ProblemeTicket>();
    ProblemeList.add(new ProblemeTicket(1,"Dysfonctionnement c2o","probleme de fonctionnement c2o") );
    ProblemeList.add(new ProblemeTicket(2,"Problème d'installation","probleme d'installation") );
    ProblemeList.add(new ProblemeTicket(3,"Modification licence","probleme de modification de la licence"));

    return ProblemeList;
}

public List<EtatSysteme> LoadEtatSysteme(){

    List<EtatSysteme> StateSystemList = new ArrayList<EtatSysteme>();
    StateSystemList.add(new EtatSysteme(1,"Complètement bloqué","Systeme complètement bloqué"));
    StateSystemList.add(new EtatSysteme(2,"Fortement perturbé","Systeme fortement perturbé"));
    StateSystemList.add(new EtatSysteme(3,"Perturbation résiduelle","Systeme qui est Perturbé résiduellement"));

    return StateSystemList;
}

public List<ContexteProblemeTicket> LoadContexteProblemeTicket(){

    List<ContexteProblemeTicket> ContexteList = new ArrayList<ContexteProblemeTicket>();
    ContexteList.add(new ContexteProblemeTicket(1,"Lors de l'installation",""));
    ContexteList.add(new ContexteProblemeTicket(2,"En cours de l'exécution",""));

    return ContexteList;
}

public List<EtatInstance> LoadEtatInstance(){

    List<EtatInstance> EtatInstanceList = new ArrayList<EtatInstance>();
    EtatInstanceList.add(new EtatInstance(1,"Aborté"," instance aborté"));
    EtatInstanceList.add(new EtatInstance(2,"En attente","instance en attente"));

    return EtatInstanceList;
}

@RequestMapping("/ticketvalide.html")
public String processTicketForm(Map model,@Valid @ModelAttribute("ticket") TicketForm ticket){


    Message message = new Message();
    message.setObjet(ticket.getSujetTicket());
    message.setTextMessage(ticket.getMessageTicket());
    message.setPath(ticket.getFile());

    iTicketMessageService.saveMessage(message);
    return "detailsticket";
}


 }
```

Comment: can you share the service and controller as well

Comment: the problem is that sessionFactory in the dao bean is not autowired

Comment: it is autowired, my doubt is you are not using the autowired instance of the dao

Comment: thnx Arun P Johny, but I use @Autowired
  private IMessageTicketDao iMessageTicketDao; in my service

Comment: I get this error  threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.gepmag.dao.MessageTicketDaoImpl.saveMessage(MessageTicketDaoImpl.java:50)
which mean that the sessionFactory is null !!